# Round date to first year of the decade in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

In Rails, I have a date saved in an instance variable. I need to grab the beginning of the decade before it. If  `@date.year= 1968` then I need to return `1960`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this several ways. As suggested, you can always use integer division which divides the number and truncates the remainder. So `1968/10` returns `196` and if you multiply it by `10`, it will give you `1960`. Or simply,

```
@date.year = @date.year/10 * 10
@date.year 
=> 1960
```

I prefer the method of using modular arithmetic. If you do `@date.year % 10` it will return the remainder if you divide by `10` which you can then subtract from the year like so:

```
@date.year = @date.year - (@date.year % 10)
@date.year 
=> 1960
```

The reason I prefer the latter is because integer division truncating the remainder may not be some thing that is obvious to everyone looking at your code. However, modular arithmetic works generally the same in all programming languages.

Keep in mind if you're trying to change the date, you need to use the appropriate [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-change).

```
@date.change(:year => 1960)
```

Comment: any way to make this return a date instead of a Fixnum?

Comment: What do you want for the month/day portion? Same as before?

Comment: yeah, it's not important, i've already run `.beginning_of_year` on it. I'm only interested in the year at this point.

Comment: You can always do `Date.new(@date.year,1,1)`. Does that help?

Comment: Also, I believe `@date` should still be a date object but with the correct year if you did it like I showed

Comment: no, I tried to do some manipulation on it and i got a no method for fixnum error, but i'll try recreating the date like that. thanks

Comment: Are you using a Date, Time or DateTime object? Also, if I've been able to help you with your question, do you mind marking this as answered again?

Comment: ok, so here's what the deal is. turns out once you call `.year` on a date it returns a fixnum. so i just started doing all my manipulation with fixnums and forgot dates all together.

Answer (score 3):

just divide and multiply integers: try `@date.year/10*10`

Comment: hah! that seems so obvious now, but i just assumed that would land me back were i started. so i was thinking /10 then round then multiply by 10... then i'd get the decade after... blah blah. forgot the integer rule.

Answer (score 2):

Do an integer division by 10, and then multiply by 10.

```
1.9.3-p286 :001 > 1855/10
 => 185 
1.9.3-p286 :002 > 185 * 10
 => 1850
```

The reason why this works (in Ruby, and in C/C++, Python, and possibly many other languages), is that integer division will always truncate the remainder. This will not be the case if you are dividing by a floating point however.